# Understanding Exact Formula for Sum of Divisors and how to program it

Tags: number-theory, education, lambert-w, bernoulli-numbers

I am trying to figure out how to put this (https://people.math.gatech.edu/~mschmidt34/images/sum-of-divisors-exact-formula.png) into computer code but I don't understand the mathematics behind 
what field of math is there and is there a way to learn more about it.

Here's the article behind [the equation abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03488).

Comment: For the purpose of computing single values of $\sigma_n(x)$, this formula seems to be more complex that the standard expansion along prime powers by multiplicativity.

Comment: Yes. See my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755267/how-to-program-formula-involving-cyclotomic-polynomials-and-lambert-series). What this formula is actually good for is expressing sums for the Mertens function in terms of the generalized sum-of-divisors functions, harmonic numbers, and the prime sums which can be asymptotically estimated if you are careful. This last sentence describes my more recent work with this article which is an ongoing research project (thesis?) of mine at GA Tech. Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what you were asking for now available [here](https://github.com/maxieds/ManuscriptComputationalData/blob/master/sod-formulas.nb). Enjoy!